# Detect if the user scrolled to the top or the bottom of a UL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to detect if the user has scrolled to the **top or the bottom** of the **UL** in a HTML Page

```
       <ul id="color-list">
              <li>Red</li>
              <li>Blue</li>
              <li>Purple</li>
              <li>Blue</li>
              <li>Yellow</li>
              <li>Black</li>
              <li>White</li>
       </ul>
```

I use this code to detect if the user scrolled to the bottom of the **page**:

```
window.onscroll = function(evt) {
     if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
         alert("End of Page") ;
     }
 }
```

Obviously this won't work for the < ul >. What changes should I make guys?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> `$().scrollTop()` return how much element has been scrolled from top
>
> `$().innerHeight()` return inner height of the element(without scroll)
>
> `DOMElement.scrollHeight` returns height of the content of the element(with scroll)

```js
$('#color-list').on('scroll', function() {
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (scrollTop + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) {
    $('#message').text('end reached');
  } else if (scrollTop <= 0) {
    $('#message').text('Top reached');
  } else {
    $('#message').text('');
  }
});
```

```css
#message {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="color-list" style="height: 150px;overflow-y: scroll">
  <li>Red</li>
  <li>Blue</li>
  <li>Purple</li>
  <li>Blue</li>
  <li>Yellow</li>
  <li>Black</li>
  <li>White</li>
  <li>Red</li>
  <li>Blue</li>
  <li>Purple</li>
  <li>Blue</li>
  <li>Yellow</li>
  <li>Black</li>
  <li>White</li>
  <li>Red</li>
  <li>Blue</li>
  <li>Purple</li>
  <li>Blue</li>
  <li>Yellow</li>
  <li>Black</li>
  <li>White</li>
  <li>Red</li>
  <li>Blue</li>
  <li>Purple</li>
  <li>Blue</li>
  <li>Yellow</li>
  <li>Black</li>
  <li>White</li>
  <li>Red</li>
  <li>Blue</li>
  <li>Purple</li>
  <li>Blue</li>
  <li>Yellow</li>
  <li>Black</li>
  <li>White</li>
  <li>Red</li>
  <li>Blue</li>
  <li>Purple</li>
  <li>Blue</li>
  <li>Yellow</li>
  <li>Black</li>
  <li>White</li>
</ul>
<div id='message'></div>
```

Comment: What about detecting the top mate?

Comment: @Earthling, It's simple.. Just add else condition like `else if ($(this).scrollTop() <= 0) {
   alert('start reached');
  }`

Answer (score 3):

So you can take the sum of scrollTop() and innerHeight(), and when they are equal to the scrollHeight() the alert is sent:

```
$('#color-list').on('scroll', function() {
     if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) {
         alert('End of List');
     }
 })
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this and let me know

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
    alert("End of Page");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed your example and this is just simpler solution if you need to check is it to the top, I needed some check to scroll to top, so here is a little changed code, maybe for someone it will be helpful:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var vLogo = jQuery(".header-logo-wrap");
    var scrollTop = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
    vLogo.addClass('logoOnScroll');
    if (scrollTop === 0) {
        vLogo.removeClass('logoOnScroll');
    }
});
});
```

So just check if it is 0, and thanks for help.. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
    var scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
    if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight === 0) {
        // when scroll to bottom of the page
        console.log("bottom")
    }
    console.log("scrollHeight:"+scrollHeight)
});
```